# Trouble finding Latias after a 'dry' internal battery in Pokemon Sapphire?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-third-generation

I have had Pokemon Sapphire for a long time and it has just recently suffered from a dry internal battery. With this given, I have also defeated the Elite 4 several times and have not received a report on Latias since.

Is my game messed up? Should I restart it, or am I not doing something correctly? I would appreciate some guidance on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>The OP's solution - originally posted in the comments:</sub>

---

The only way for the battery to resume time is to restart the game.

As much as I hated to do it, I restarted the game and now everything is working properly.